# Does the king of France really have hair?

Tags: logic

AFAIK, every statement must be either true or false (or a paradox, but that's not what I am talking about now), by the law of the excluded middle.

The statement *"The king of France is bald."* is false, because there is no king of France. But then, by the same law, shouldn't *"The king of France is **not** bald."*, that is, *"The king of France has hair."*, be true?

The only possibility I can think of to solve this confusion is that the opposite of a statement is not what we usually think it is, and as *"The king of France is bald."* means *"The king of France exists."* and *"**If** he does exist, he is bald."*, that is *"If the king of France exists, then he is bald."*.

Maybe as *"If the king of France exists, then he is bald."* equals *"The king of France doesn't exist and/or he is bald."*, the opposite should be (by DeMorgan's laws) *"The king of France exists and he isn't bald."*, but that's even more awkward.

So what should the opposite of this should be? The converse? The inverse? The contrapositive cannot be, it would be false as well. Can you give me a hand here?

Comment: You're making a mistake with "every statement must be either true or false or a paradox". Some statements are meaningless. For example, "my height smells of mangoes". Your example sentence makes an invalid presupposition. Also, is it true that you have stopped beating your wife?

Comment: As I never beat my wife, it is not true that I have stopped beating my wife.  It is perfectly allowable that a statement implies another truth.  You imply that "At some point I beat my wife" when you make your statement.  That statement being false makes yours false too.  And your height does not smell of mangoes, so that is false too.

Comment: @prash, so you reject the law of the excluded middle?

Comment: @prash - the statement "my height smells of mangoes" is actually provably false, as we can determine by [hypostatic abstraction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypostatic_abstraction).  "my height smells of mangoes" can be decomposed into the set of statements:  `{ "i have a height, H" ,  "H has a smell, S1" , "mangoes have a smell, S2", "S1 = S2" }`.  The proposition "H has a smell, S1" is a necessary component of the statement "my height smells of mangoes" and is known to be false, thereby making the entire statement false.

Comment: @smartcaveman: I agree. My height is odorless.

Comment: @JMCF125: I do no such thing. See this article on presupposition failure: http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/presupposition/.

Comment: @Ryno: "It is perfectly allowable that a statement implies another truth." Not quite. It violates the maxim of relevance. "I am not pregnant" is true. "I am not pregnant anymore" makes a false presupposition, and there is no point in assigning a truth value to the statement: the statement is irrelevant. Contrast "The US has stopped bombing Afghanistan" and "The US has stopped bombing China".

Comment: I disagree.  The US has not stopped bombing China.  The statement is false, not meaningless.  The truth of it may be "irrelevant" but it is not "undefined".  Short of a paradox, as the OP mentions, you cannot create a factual statement that cannot be evaluated.  "Burger King tastes better than McDonalds" is an example of a statement that sounds like a fact, but can't be evaluated (it's a matter of opinion, not a factual statement).

Comment: "I am not pregnant anymore" makes me think though (and makes me need a second comment).  ("I am not pregnant" and "I used to be pregnant") is false.  But does "any more" really mean "And I used to be"?  It seems "any more" is weaker than that.  Can anyone suggest a better interpretation?

Comment: And (and sorry for the comment spam) - @prash that stanford article specifically says that "The King of France is bald" can be evaluated, and is False.  Context may change the listener's judgement of the sentence, but the sentence can be evaluated as False.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11617/discussion-between-prash-and-ryno)

Comment: Who down-voted this? May someone please explain? Does this not contribute to knowledge of us all in logic?

Comment: To deny that a meaningless sentence has a truth value isn't to deny the law of excluded middle. Truth values attach to propositions. By claiming the sentence is meaningless, you are denying that it expresses a proposition--- no proposition, no truth value.

Comment: @Dennis, yes, some statements are logically meaningless (such as orders or opinions), but not because they refer non-existing entities. prash seems to be taking, as I think I was, a wrong definition of "opposite".

Comment: I disagree that "The king of France is bald" is false. It's only a well-formed proposition if there is exactly one king of France. If there is no king of France, or if there are more than one king of France, then it is malformed and there is no point in trying to assign this sentence a truth-value, since it is not a well-formed proposition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement "The King of France is bald" would usually mean "The King Of France exists, and has no hair".  It could be taken to mean a few other things, but this is the meaning I will assume for this answer, and regardless of what you assume it to mean, you can use the same method I will use below to derive the opposite.

Let X = The King of France
Let A = X exists 
Let B = X has no hair

Truth Table:
     BT     BF
AT    .
AF

The dot in that truth table represents the situation "The King of France is Bald".

The opposite would be 
     BT     BF
AT           .
AF    .      .

Which is (A&!B) or (!A&B) or (!A&!B)
which simplifies to (!A or (A&!B)) 
It can also simplify to (!B or (!A&B))

which in english is "The King of France does not exist, or he exists and has hair"
or "The King of France has hair, or he does not exist and has hair".

As the second translation doesn't really make sense, we take the first.  (As, in this case, the second sentence only has a value if the first is true).

If you interpret the original sentence to be a different combination of facts, or some dependency between the two sentences, then your original truth table is different, but to find the opposite, you take the truth table with every combination being opposite, and interpret from there.

Another popular interpretation would be "There exists a King of France such that it is bald."  The opposite of that one is "There does not exist a King of France such that it is bald," which is quite clearly true.

Comment: I should have made a truth table before asking indeed... My problem was in (!B or (!A&B)), which as you referred, is a senseless interpretation in this case. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Yep - the difference between logical/syntactic sense, and "English" sense... :)